# type mismatch assigning range to 1d array

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a range in a text format containing values and numbers. I am trying to assign the numbers only to an array and then I will assign the text values to another array without having to loop through the range. However, this code says - type mismatch?

```
  Sub Igra()
  Dim Arr() As Variant
  'convert the range values from text to general
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").NumberFormat = "General"
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").Value
  ' assign only the numbers to the array
  Arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Value
  End Sub
```

This should work then

```
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
    Arr = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
       For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
          MsgBox Arr(R, C)
    Next C
  Next R
```

Comment: See here: [Excel VBA: Populate array with range from specific sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859531/excel-vba-populate-array-with-range-from-specific-sheet).

Comment: I do exactly the same as there but it doesn't work. Is it because the cells might not be adjacent?

Comment: It's probably because, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx), `SpecialCells` *returns a Range object that represents all the cells that match the specified type and value.* So perhaps it's not matching anything, so calling `.Value` on nothing is probably the reason for the error.

Comment: It is matching something though. When I do Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R32:W32").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).select I can see matched selected values from my example

Comment: Hi, yeah I saw the answer. It says - Dim arr
Set arr = Range("A1, C1"). However, in my case I don't know the address of the cells so I can't use A1,C1 etc

Comment: but I trying doing simply 
Dim arr() As Variant and then arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:B10") which are adjacent and it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: yes, I did. Thanks for that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rng = ws.Range("R32:W32")

    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(rng)

    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ReDim Arr(1 To n)

    i = 1

    For Each cl In rng
        If IsNumeric(cl.Value) Then
            Arr(i) = cl.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cl

    '~~> Only for demonstration purpose
    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It still says type mismatch

Comment: May I see your worksheet as the above code is tried and tested.

Comment: This is a link to the excel sheet. I left only the relevant cells
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgzr8y9uj3mbhxr/test.xlsx

Comment: No, R32 is not blank. All cells are filled in with values

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing. One moment. Updating my post

Comment: Hi, yeah, it is pretty much. Thanks but I was trying not use a loop as I said in my first post mainly for efficiency purposes. So doing the same thing with one line of code is not possible? Only a loop?

Comment: If you have mixed data then yes, you will have to use a loop.

Comment: and If the is not mixed? If there are only numbers in a row?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my first post. It ll be a lot simpler and efficient first to copy the numbers somewhere in the sheet and then paste them so that they are adjacent. And then assign them to the Array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah but this is just an example. I will have to do this for a large data set